# Springboot - serve index.html when / is hit

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am deploying an embedded Angular + Springboot app on Docker. (The Angular app is built and is available inside src/main/resources/static).

I am able to access the Angular app using http://localhost:80/index.html

**What I want :**

When the user hits either of the 2 urls:
/ or anything other than **/mealplanner/**, serve index.html

I am not using thymeleaf.

**What I tried:**

FIX 1: WORKING
I also added the below code to SpringBoot :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "index.html");
    }
}
```

When I hit the url localhost:80/, it redirects to localhost:80/index.html and displays the correct page. I do not want to use this option because my url looks very strange when I use subpaths.

FIX 2: NOT WORKING

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    }
}
```

**NOT WORKING**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index.html");
    }
}
```

**NOT WORKING**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("static/index.html");
    }
}
```

Incase it matters, I am using Docker to deploy it on my local system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as far as i know , you can create folder named static if it is not exists, under the resources folder and add a index.html in that static folder, spring boot automatically will open that html file when you hit "/" endpoint

Comment: There are existing solutions in reverse proxy servers. I would say, the easiest method is to use an Nginx server, because you can directly rewrite URL and `try index.html` in its configuration. Do you wish to add a reverse proxy?

Comment: Yes, I would like to add a reverse proxy. Can you pls give me an example?